# Discord.js client.addMemberToRole not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I'm programming a Discord bot, and one of the things I want it to do is to assign roles to members given certain conditions. After looking through the documentation, specifically [here](http://discordjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs_client.html#addmembertorole-member-role-callback), I figured bot.addMemberToRole would be a good command to use. However, when I ran it, I got this error message:

TypeError: bot.addMemberToRole is not a function

I was understandably confused, as the documentation clearly says that this IS a function. I have tried doing bot.addMemberToRole(member, role);, addMemberToRole(member, role);, and several other iterations. This is my most recent attempt:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.addMemberToRole(member, role, function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I have also done just this:

```
bot.addMemberToRole(member, role);
```

Both gave the same TypeError as above.

I have no idea why it doesn't work. I followed the documentation exactly, the member and role variables I pass into it are the proper type, and other Discord.js commands work just fine in my bot. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an old version of the docs so that function doesn't exist anymore. They should really get rid of those. You're looking for `GuildMember.addRole(Role or String)`.

To add a member to a role, you need a GuildMember and a Role object (or the name of the role). Assuming you have the User object and the Guild object (your bot has a list of the guilds/servers it's joined and most events will have the guild they're associated with), you can get the GuildMember by using `Guild.fetchMember(User)`. From there, you can add the role on the GuildMember using either the string or object based version of addRole.

Here's an example of how to do it upon receiving a message from a user which is very easy since the message has a GuildMember associated with it.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js'); 
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.on('message', (message) => {
  const guildMember = message.member;
  guildMember.addRole('bot-added-role');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!